# Can a single SELECT significantly degrade the performance of an Oracle Database?

Tags: performance, oracle

All,

Consider

- an Oracle Database of version 10gR2 or greater.
- Hardware sufficient to exceed existing peak workload by more than 100%

Can you construct any circumstance in which a single user with a single connection and read-only access to user tables (not system tables or v$ or x$ tables) degrade the overall performance of an Oracle database. Also list mitigation strategy if any.

As stipulated, consider that this is not about a database which is a few CPU-cycles away from saturation such that any additional load would be dangerous. This is about a well sized box for the current workload.

E.G.

If a user uses a parallel hint, Oracle may use a very high DOP to execute that query and starve other processes of CPU. Mitigation: explain to user that Parallel hints are forbidden.

Comment: ru considering anonymous pl/sql blocks as well?

Comment: Good question. Justin mentioned that below. My use is just SQL but I'd love to hear about those problems as well.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest approach would be to issue a query that does a Cartesian product of your biggest table with itself a bunch of times.  That will blow out your `TEMP` tablespace rather quickly and generate errors for other sessions that need to sort.  You can mitigate that either by granting limited quotas on `TEMP` (which may get tricky if this is an application account that is used by multiple people simultaneously rather than an individually identifiable account) or by using Resource Manager to kill sessions that either run too long or that use too much CPU or I/O resources.

Even without an explicit `PARALLEL` hint, it's possible that Oracle will use parallelism automatically.  Depending on the Oracle version and how you've configured parallelism, turning on parallel automatic tuning to limit the total number of parallel workers at any time.  Of course, that doesn't prevent the read-only user from creating a dozen sessions each of which spawns a couple of parallel workers that choke off other sessions that you actually want to run more parallel workers.  You can use Resource Manager to configure priorities for different types of workload if and when the system becomes CPU constrained.

And if you allow an anonymous PL/SQL block, there are more ways to generate havoc by, for example, creating a nested table that gets filled with billions of rows until your PGA is exhausted.

Comment: Ach, I was just typing a disgusting cartesian join. I would add that I've recently had my box taken down by someone who was re-connecting  for each iteration of a loop. It's not just queries that need to be looked out for.

Comment: Temp I had considered. Thanks for listing it and the strategy. As to your mitigation, I appreciate you went above the call but this isn't an app account. The use case is one user, one connection. Is it possible to have more than one Temp tablespace that is assigned by user?

Comment: @StephaniePage - Yes, you can assign different `TEMP` tablespaces for different users, at least in recent Oracle versions.  Not sure if you could back in the 8i or 9i days.

Comment: Pretty sure you couldn't back then.